# JSP global variable

Tags: java, jsp, global-variables

I have this code

```
<%!  
   public String class_name = "";  
%>  
<c:choose>
      <c:when test="${WCParam.categoryId != null}">
        <% class_name = "my_account_custom"; %>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <% class_name = "my_account_custom_3"; %>
      </c:otherwise>    
</c:choose>    
<p>Class name = <c:out value='${class_name}' /></p>
```

WCParam.categoryId is null or not
But my class_name variable is always empty. 
What i am doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: You'll likely want to be very careful regarding variables declared `<%! %>`, IIRC they are instance variables, thus shared across all users of that page. This *may* be okay, but IMO it should be avoided, like all scriptlets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scriptlets (`<%...%>`) and expression language (`${...}`) are completely different things, therefore their variables belong to different scopes (variables used in EL expressions are actually request attributes of different scopes).

If you decalred `class_name` as a scriptlet variable, you should access it using scriptlet as well:

```
<p>Class name = <c:out value='<%=class_name%>' /></p>
```

However, you can write it without using a variable at all:

```
<p>Class name = <c:out 
     value='${WCParam.categoryId != null ? "my_account_custom" : "my_account_custom3"}' /></p>
```

Comment: +1: that's true.  el (${}) are used to access scope variables (app, session, request and page) and they can't access to variables that are defined within scriptlet